# Shutdown Problem

Tags: shutdown

Hi this is my first post and have a problem.
I have just updated today and found that when I try to shutdown a box comes on screen and it says

```
Received Error When Trying To Logout
Session Manager Must Be In Idle State
When Requesting Shutdown
```

I can shutdown By holding the power button down. I have a Dell Latitude 2100.
Is there anyone who can help me with this I have not had much to do with Linux Ubuntu 14.04 I think it is. Thanks for reading this

Comment: Have you tried the init 0 command for shutdown?

Answer (score -1):

If the desktop in question is xfce, check the following thread:

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6580

For me post 17 - delete the session file in

```
$HOME/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-*
```

did the trick. The session file gets sometimes corrupted -
once I was not able to login to XFCE - deleting the session file
also solved that problem...

**Note:** Don't delete the session file. Just rename or move it. So in case the
problem persists after XFCE created a new pristine session file you can go back
to your old one.

**UPDATE 2020:**

More than 10 years after this problem was first reported, it persists in 18.04.

Sessions are now files with pattern `xfwm4-*.state`, and stored in `~/.cache/sessions`. Renaming these session files does not fix the immediate problem, though they are quite nice to look at.

In absence of a fix, **force a shutdown** (perhaps once you have manually closed all programs):

`sudo shutdown -h now`

**It is *possible* however, that renaming the sessions files prevents the problem from recurring again.** It has not recurred for me, for now, immediately after a forced shutdown, perhaps because I renamed all `~/.cache/sessions/xfwm4*.state` files first.

An [antique request for help in the XFCE forums](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6580&p=2) suggests switching on the facility to save sessions, which can be done in `settings > sessions & startup`.

Comment: I tried this , and it says " no such file "

Comment: to make sure you running XFCE,  check output of                                   `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`, should give you XFCE. Then check your users cache for XFCE session files: `find ~/.cache -type f -name "xfce*session*"`

Answer (score -2):

Try removing unity and then reinstalling unity via recovery mode.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then click dpkg in recovery mode
Click on continue

Now try shutting down

Comment: I tride this and it says

Comment: I tried this and it says       unable to locate package apt get     unable to locate  remove desktop    unable to locate apt get    unable to locate package install    unable to locate apt get    unable to locate package install

Comment: This problem occurs with xfce4.